# How to add a context menu to a `gframe`?

Tags: r, contextmenu, gwidgets

How can I add a context menu to a `gframe` in `gWidgets2`? I tried the following construct, but it seems that I cannot attach a `addPopupMenu` to a `gframe`:

```
 require(gWidgets2)
 w <- gwindow("gformlayout", visible=T)
 f <- gframe("frame", horizontal=FALSE, container=w)
 l <- glabel("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \nconsectetur adipiscing elit.", container=f)
 b <- gbutton("change name", container=f, handler=function(h,...) {
     names(f) <- "new name"
 })
 lst <- list(gaction('world', handler=function(h,...) svalue(world) <- "world"), 
             gaction('continent', handler=function(h,...) svalue(world) <- "continent"), 
             gaction('country', handler=function(h,...) svalue(world) <- "country"), 
             gaction('state', handler=function(h,...) svalue(world) <- "state"))
 add3rdmousePopupMenu(f, lst)
 #addPopupMenu(f, lst)
 add3rdmousePopupMenu(b, lst)
```

The context-menu is attached fine to the button, but NOT to the `gframe`. So how can I add a context menu that would pop-up when right-clicking the `gframe` label?

---

**UPDATE**
As per the answers, I tried the code below:

```
require(gWidgets2)
f <- gframe("", cont=gwindow())
l <- glabel("label")                    # no cont argument
add3rdmousePopupMenu(l, list(a=gaction("Hi"))) 
f$block$setLabelWidget(l$block)         # the voodoo
```

But when I `right-click` on the `label`, I only get the standard Gtk context menu for selecting text:

[image]

Using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gtk+ 2.24.23. My `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape2_1.4         gWidgets2RGtk2_1.0-3 memoise_0.2.1        Hmisc_3.14-4         Formula_1.1-1       
 [6] survival_2.37-7      lattice_0.20-29      RGtk2_2.20.29        gWidgets2_1.0-6      digest_0.6.4        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] cluster_1.14.4      latticeExtra_0.6-26 plyr_1.8.1          RColorBrewer_1.0-5  Rcpp_0.11.2        
[6] stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: It has something to do with `add3rdmousePopupMenu`, which I say based on glancing at the source code. I'll try to make a proper solution for you if I have time.

Comment: added it as a solution. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@landroni I didn't check, but would be surprised if popup menus could be added to gframe labels directly. But with Gtk things can be worked around. Here is how you can put a popup menu in the label position:

```
f <- gframe("", cont=gwindow())
l <- glabel("label")                    # no cont argument
add3rdmousePopupMenu(l, list(a=gaction("Hi"))) 
f$block$setLabelWidget(l$block)         # the voodoo
l$widget$setSelectable(FALSE)           # may not be needed
```

As for whether this is intuitive to the users, I'll let you decide....

Comment: Good point on the usability, and this gave me an idea for a different GUI approach. However, the code above doesn't seem to work: I still get the GTK standard menu for a text widget. Perhaps the `glabel` should first be made non-selectable?

Comment: For an example of this, if you do `l2 <- glabel("label", cont=gwindow()); add3rdmousePopupMenu(l2, list(a=gaction("Hi")))`, the c-menu on the `glabel` won't work..

Comment: @landroni Oops, it should be `add3rdmousePopupMenu`. (I need to make an alias to `add3rdMousePopupMenu`, as that camel-casing seems more natural.) That works on linux. If it doesn't work with this change let me know.

Comment: Strange. Here on Linux, too, I don't get a c-menu with the code posted (even when fixing the typo and using the correct `add3rdmousePopupMenu`).

Comment: @landroni I just double checked with a new unbuntu install and it is working. Do you get any errors, or just no response>

Comment: I updated the Question with the exact code that I'm running and a screenshot of the issue I'm seeing.

Comment: Okay, I'm stumped. It works for my Ubuntu (14.04). Not sure where to go as I don't see any error messages. Seems like the default menu is being called instead of the new one, so the popup bit works, but not the adding of a menu. Sorry.

Comment: I suspect that the issue comes from the `glabel` being *selectable*. For instance, when you use `gframe` the label text can NOT be selected by the user. How could I make `l <- glabel("label")` NOT selectable at all?

Comment: `l$widget$setSelectable(FALSE)` should do that.

Comment: Nice. Glad to hear it.

Comment: But what if I wanted to put such a customized `gframe` into a `glayout` grid slot? I tried the following: `gl <- glayout(cont=gwindow()); gl[1,1] <- gframe("", cont=gl); l <- glabel("label")`, but no luck. How can you put such a construct into a `glayout`?

Comment: Should work just as before. Maybe you need to save the `gframe` object into a variable for convenience?

Comment: Hmm, it does seem to work. Not sure what was wrong before. If I still hit trouble, I'll post a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

A popup menu “pops” up a menu after a mouse click, typically a right mouse click.
Implemented in gWidgets are the functions 1add3rdmousepopupmenu`(the one you want) and`addpopupmenu` for a popup on any click. The menu is specified using the syntax for gmenu.

A simple example would be something like:

```
> w <- gwindow("Click on button to change")
> g <- ggroup(cont = w) # abbreviate container
> glabel("Hello ", cont=g)
guiWidget of type: gLabelRGtk for toolkit: guiWidgetsToolkitRGtk2
> world <- gbutton("world", cont=g)
> lst <- list()
> lst$world$handler <- function(h,...) svalue(world) <- "world"
> lst$continent$handler <- function(h,...) svalue(world) <- "continent"
> lst$country$handler <- function(h,...) svalue(world) <- "country"
> lst$state$handler <- function(h,...) svalue(world) <- "state"
> add3rdmousepopupmenu(world, lst)
```

I had a chance to test this and it works for me with `gWidgets`, `gWidgets2`, and `gWidgetsRGtk2` using 64-bit R 3.1.1 on Windows. You can find documentation for the `add3rdmousepopupmenu` handler

1. in the `gWidgets2` manual [here](https://github.com/jverzani/gWidgets2/blob/master/man/gWidgets-handlers.Rd) or
2. by typing `??add3rdmousepopupmenu` with `gWidgets2` loaded,
3. in the [recently updated document by the author John Verzani](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/vignettes/gWidgets.pdf) giving examples for the gWidgets API, which applies not only to `gWdigets2`, but also his `gWidgets`, `gWidgetsQt`, `gWidgetsRGtk2`, and `gWidgetsrJava` packages which call the **gWdigets API**
4. and in the `gWidgets2` [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets2/gWidgets2.pdf) on CRAN

Comment: I tried this but both `add3rdmousePopupMenu(world, lst)` and ` addPopupMenu(world, lst)` result in `Error in UseMethod("getBlock") : 
  no applicable method for 'getBlock' applied to an object of class "function"` when using `gWidgets2`. Not sure what is wrong..

Comment: @landroni I will try to help you with that. You should add it to the question though or break them into two different questions. I will update my solution as soon as I think I know what's causing your error. Please include the exact code that leads to that error.

Comment: I can't replicate the error and I don't see any search results related to it... can you give a replicable example?

Comment: I simply ran `require(gWidgets2)`, then the code you posted, and instead of the last line: `add3rdmousePopupMenu(world, lst)`.

Comment: @landroni I see. I'm still not able to replicate that error, however I tried it again and noticed that `add3rdmousepopupmenu` should not have the "P" in "Popup" capitalized. Sorry about that, in my defensive that is a copy and paste from authoritative documentation; apparently they had a typo since the "P" in `addPopupmenu` is in fact capitalized. It works for me. Does that fix it for you too?

Comment: No, not really, I tried with the capitalized, too. BTW, that document must have been for the old version: `gWidgets`, and some changes have taken place.

Comment: @landroni the documentation was published July 14, 2014... can you paste your code, output and the output of `R.Version`?

Comment: Could you link to the documentation you're referring to? Thanks.

Comment: @landroni Sure, done. If you have any more/continued errors please consider pasting your code and version information and/or continuing this in chat. StackOverflow is officially warnings us that there are too many comments LOL

Comment: Thanks @NerdLife. The documentation is not always correct, but I'm happy to try and update. I need to be more clear about the difference between `gWidgets` and `gWidgets2`. Most things are similar, but there were enough changes to make the additional `2` warranted. Any docs for `gWidgets` are old, even if the package was updated recently.

Comment: @jverzani Yes it would be nice to have a short list of fundamental differences between `gWidgets` and `gWidgets2`. It would come in handy if one wanted to port a `gWidgets` package (e.g. `latticist`) to `gWidgets2`.

Comment: Could you please recheck the question, @jverzani? The code works fine to add a context-menu to a `gbutton`, but NOT to a `gframe`. Maybe a bug..

Comment: The code that you posted was taken from the `gWidgets` vignette, but it does NOT work with `gWidgets2` (they're not perfectly compatible). In the latter, `addPopupMenu` expects a `list` of `gaction` objects, NOT `function` objs.