# Issues with assigning handlers through a loop

Tags: r, loops, handler, lazy-evaluation, gwidgets

On the back of [How to add a context menu to a `gframe`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513254/how-to-add-a-context-menu-to-a-gframe), I am trying to create three different `gframe` objects with different context-menu handlers. To avoid code duplication, I'm doing this through a loop.

Consider this minimal example:

```
require(gWidgets2)
require(gWidgets2RGtk2)
w <- gwindow()
gg <- gvbox(cont=w)                   

f_lyt_ctab <- list()
l_lyt_ctab <- list()

h_ctab_clear  <- function(field.nr=NULL){
    stopifnot(!is.null(field.nr))
    print(field.nr)
}

lyt_ctab <- glayout(homogeneous=F, cont=gg, expand=TRUE, fill=T)
field.nms <- c("Row Fields", "Column Fields", "Values")
for(i in 1:3){
    lyt_ctab[1,i, expand=TRUE, fill=T] <- 
        f_lyt_ctab[[i]] <- gframe("", horizontal=FALSE,
                                  container=lyt_ctab, expand=TRUE, fill=T)
    ##have gframe with custom label (and context menu)
    l_lyt_ctab[[i]] <- glabel(field.nms[i])
    tooltip(l_lyt_ctab[[i]]) <- paste(
        "Right-click on", field.nms[i], "to clear field variables")
    print(i)
    print(field.nms[i])
    add3rdmousePopupMenu(l_lyt_ctab[[i]], 
                         list(a=gaction("Clear field", icon="clear", 
                                        handler=function(h, ...){
                                            h_ctab_clear(field.nr=i)
                                        })))
    f_lyt_ctab[[i]]$block$setLabelWidget(l_lyt_ctab[[i]]$block)         # the voodoo
    l_lyt_ctab[[i]]$widget$setSelectable(FALSE)           # may not be needed
}
```

The trouble is that for some reason the

`handler=function(h, ...){
     h_ctab_clear(field.nr=i)
     })`

does not seem to get passed the correct `i` value. It is always `3`. So whichever context-menu is accessed, it's only the `h_ctab_clear(field.nr=3)` that gets executed.

I'm stumped if for the simple reason that the `gframe` tooltips are all correct. But not the handler associated with each context menu.

I'm suspecting some scope or similar issue with `h_ctab_clear(field.nr=i)`, but I'm not sure what is wrong?

Comment: I have no idea what this code is supposed to do since it doesn't appear to be [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (ie, when I paste it into R i get a bunch of errors starting with "No toolkit packages are installed" from `gwindow`). But ignoring that for now, i'm guessing the problem is due to lazy evaluation of parameter values. Formally doing something like `force(i)` will help turn the promise value if `i` into an actual value but where you would put that in this case is unclear. Please make your code runnable.

Comment: The code is reproducible. You probably need to `install.packages("gWidgets2RGtk2")`. As for your comment, I was also suspecting something related to " lazy evaluation" or similar, but I'm not sure how to work around that.

Comment: Sure, will do so. Usually it works fine with just `require(gWidgets2)`, but obviously it fails when user hasn't installed `gWidgets2RGtk2`. Will be more careful next time.

Comment: For Mac, you would need to have the development libraries of Gtk2 installed. (On Ubuntu Linux it's `libgtk2.0-dev`.) I'll test your suggestion and get back.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. I tried your suggestion exactly, but nothing seems to be happening. Not even an error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60783/discussion-between-mrflick-and-landroni).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `add3rdmousePopupMenu` is probably taking your `handler` function and evaluating it in a different context. At that point, it can't resolve `i` because it's a free variable in the function body and the original enclosure environment is no longer available. One possible solution is to explicitly create an enclosure that hold the `i` value. To make this easier, we can create a helper function.

```
makehandler <- function(i) {
    force(i); 
    function(h, ...){
        h_ctab_clear(field.nr=i)
    }
}
```

This function will enclose `i` and then return a function that you can use as a handler. Then you can use it like

```
add3rdmousePopupMenu(l_lyt_ctab[[i]], 
    list(a=gaction(
        "Clear field", 
        icon="clear", 
        handler=makehandler(i)
    ))
)
```

Comment: Sometimes this scoping issue can be resolved by using `sapply` in place of the for loop, as then the `i` value is within the environment of the function call. The `force` trick is another possible solution.